# Python X13NotFoundError

Tags: python, forecasting

How can I call the X13 procedure from Python? I have installed Python 3.6.8 and running them on Windows 10 machine within Spyder IDE. Below is the sample python code I am running. However, when I run I am getting

```
X13NotFoundError: x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the path, put them on PATH, or set the X12PATH or X13PATH environmental variable.
```

I have downloaded the `winx13_V2.5` version from [here](https://www.census.gov/srd/www/winx13/winx13_down.html) and unzipped to a folder with in C directory. I am using the below python code to set the path variable and call the `x13_arima_analysis` method. However, as I said I am getting X13 not found error.

```
from pandas import read_csv
import statsmodels.api as sm

dailyTemp = read_csv('//ds/S/users2/SXM024/CCF Files/CCF_Old_Laptop_shortcut/CCF_DeskopFiles/Books_Articles_litreatures/MachinelearningMastery/time_series_forecasting_with_python/code/chapter_05/daily-minimum-temperatures.csv', header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)

X13PATH= "C:\\X13\\winx13_V2.5\\WinX13\\x13as"

x13results = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=dailyTemp.values, x12path=X13PATH, outlier=True, print_stdout=True, freq=1, prefer_x13=True)
```

Comment: `X13PATH` in your code is a local variable, not an environment variable. You need to set it *outside* the script.

Comment: Hello - Thanks for your prompt response. I did set an environment variable and re ran code. I got the same error. Any ideas?                           
os.environ["X13PATH"] = "C:\\X13\\winx13_V2.5\\WinX13\\x13exec"                                  sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=dailyTemp.values, outlier=True, print_stdout=True, freq=1, prefer_x13=True)